# How to save to data into database which is in array format

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have this following array. I want to insert data into two tables on single save link. How can I do this?

First three fields will save in products table and the `opt_vals`, which is an array, will be saved in another table called as `product_links`.

Also I want to insert `lastInsertId` into `product_links` table. `product_links` fields as `id`, `product_id`, `product_values`.

```
Array
(
    [Product] => Array
    (
        [product_name] => 
        [product_desc] => 
        [price] => 
        [opt_vals] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 
                    )
           )
    )
)
```

Comment: Which database are you using? You could use transactions.

Comment: You should start by reading the docs on **[associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)** and **[saving data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)**.

Comment: Check this link: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php and all the links in the `See also` section.

Comment: @tastro CakePHP comes with an ORM and has it's own transaction support (if the DB supports them), NDMs links are the right way to go.

Comment: @burzum sorry, my bad... I didn't see the CakePHP tag.

Answer (score 0):

Please use model associan `$belongTo` in your model after that you can use

```
$this->Model->savAll($this->request->data);
```